# Python command is not recognized anymore

Tags: python, cmd, octoprint

I have installed Python 2.7 on my pc. I have checked the PATH and it is there. 
The python command in the command prompter was working fine. 
I have updated the pip through cmd, then installed virtualenv, and then worked a while through cmd. 
I was working on the octoprint plugin tutorial, but after I run the octoprint serve once, the next time it stops recognizing everything, including python and pip commands. The environmental path is still there, untouched. I have no idea on why it is happening.

Someone got anything like that?

OS Windows 10
Tried cmd and powershell

Comment: do `echo %PATH%` from your shell and find Python there. Could be that your environment variable is too long (there's a max length to these, for some unknown reason)

Comment: What is weird is that the command was working. I then ran the octoprint server, and it ran sucessfully, but after I stopped it, everything broke.

Comment: When using venv (comes with Python) I remove any Python from the PATH and depend on `activate.bat` to configure things correctly.